# do sstablesplit on the side

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

As sstables are immutable and sstable split has to be performed offline ie. with node shutdown. Wouldn't it also be possible to split copies of extreme large sstables offline/in a sideline dir, while keeping a node online then following swap the extreme sstables with a set of splitted sstable files during a short restart of a node to minimize node downtime?

Or would it be better to decommission a node, spreading data over rest of cluster and then rejoin as a new empty node

Eg. having some large sstables which ain't getting into a compaction view any time soon. I'll like to split such offline say in another directory/FS/on another box, just where ever out of scope from running node while still having the node servicing redundancy from original sstable path. Only it seems sstablesplit want to find the configuration or can it be tricked to otherwise do a split out-reach from the running node?

Tried on a copy of a sstable file to split it, but:

> on-a-offlinebox$ sstablesplit --debug -s SOME-VALUE-IN-MB mykeyspc-mycf-*-Data.db 16:58:13.197 [main] ERROR o.a.c.config.DatabaseDescriptor - Fatal
>   configuration error
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI
>   in variable: [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:///
>   for local files or file:/// for remote files. Aborting. If you
>   are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set
>   Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:73)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.15.jar:2.1.15]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:84)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.15.jar:2.1.15]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:161)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.15.jar:2.1.15]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.15.jar:2.1.15]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.tools.StandaloneSplitter.main(StandaloneSplitter.java:56)
>   [apache-cassandra-2.1.15.jar:2.1.15] Expecting URI in variable:
>   [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:/// for local
>   files or file:/// for remote files. Aborting. If you are
>   executing this from an external tool, it needs to set
>   Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration. Fatal
>   configuration error; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford downtime for the node, just do it (split the tables). Anyway, if you will do this split on another machine/another dir you will need to run repair on the node (due to "offline" time of the rebuilded tables) after reloading sstables.

You can also try to drop this tables data files from your node and running repair, it will be probably minimal downtime for the node:

Stop the node -> Delete big sstables -> Start the node -> Repair.

EDIT: Since Cassandra 3.4, you can run compact command on specific sstables/files. On any earlier version, you can use forceUserDefinedCompaction jmx call. You can use one of these, or make a jmx call by yourself:

http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/manual.html

https://github.com/hancockks/cassandra-compact-cf

https://gist.github.com/jeromatron/e238e5795b3e79866b83

Example code with jmxterm:

```
sudo java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l localhost:7199

bean org.apache.cassandra.db:type=CompactionManager
run forceUserDefinedCompaction YourKeySpaceName_YourFileName.db
```

Also, if "big tables" problem occurs all the time, consider moving to LCS.

Comment: Reason we want to do a compaction on such large sstables are that we expect to have many tombstones for quite some data residing in the large sstables. TSs were created +30 days ago now so they are long overdue gc_grace at default 10 days. Only it'll be a long time before such TSs would get compacted against few excessive few large sstables. Our App Vendor says run major compac every night and don't use vnodes as we do relying on minor compacs. Would TSed data also be spread on a decom or only 'live-data', ie. could a decom-rejoin work similar to a major compac for the individual node?

Comment: AFAIK, both rebuild and decommission have nothing to do with compaction - they just stream data.  Please review my edit to the answer.

Comment: I meant that if decom didn't stream TS shadowed data from big table, then the effect after a decom+rejoin could be similar to compacting away TSed data. single file compaction is properly only useful if same file hold TTL expired data otherwise to reclaim disk space we'll need also to consider our App genereated TSs from other smallere tables. See http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: Again, AFAIK, decommission WILL stream TSed data, and no compaction will be performed.

Comment: I see three options w/TSs in smallere tables and old data pushed to a big table(s). 1) do major compactions (aiming to keep your CF data in one [big] table, 2) decom+rejoin (lot of data shuffling wo/vnodes), 3) offline and do sstablesplit. 1+2 maintain full redundancy during the operation, 3 don't, 1 may mean keep doing major compactions regulary otherwise we soon ended likewise. App Vendor don't recommend LCS, but STCS+regulary major compac+no vnodes. We're on STCS+vnodes+not-happy-doing-majors-due-to-load...

Comment: So if decom do stream TSed data then we ought to aim at doing major compactions to reclaim disk space and keep redunancy during operation...

Comment: One of the problems LCS is solving is your scenario with big tables that never compacted... Since your data can be spread in several sstables, the only way to reclaim all space used by old/TSed data is to perform major compaction.